# Write a regex for a pattern?

Tags: python, regex

`a + (ab or cd ) + g` is my expression. How can I write a regex in Python to match these?

Comment: I don't understand the expression you want. Suggest you extend the post to give a few example lines of text, some that match what you want some that don't. Then we can clearly see what you are trying to match.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? Are you just looking to concatenate `a` and `ab` or `cd` and `e` once or do you need this in a recursive fashion?

Answer (score 0):

To search this regex in a string, say

```
re.search("a\\+((ab)|(cd))\\+g", your_string)
```

To extract matches, use `re.findall` etc. No need to copy&paste [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) here. :)

EDIT: Updated after OP changed the regex.

If you want it to match whitespace in between, things get pretty ugly ...

```
re.search("a\W*\\+\W*((ab)|(cd))\W*\\+\W*g", your_string)
```

Comment: Just to make sure it's clear, the `+` has a particular meaning in regular expressions. So if you want to literally match the `+` character itself, you need to escape it: `"(a\\+b)|(cd\\+e)"`

Comment: @MatrixFrog: Ok ... after his last edit I understand he was looking for literal "+" indeed.

Comment: Can't this be re-written as `re.search(r"a\W*\+\W*(ab|cd)\W*\+\W*g", your_string)`? Use a raw string so you don't ahve to escape everything twice, and you don't need the extra pair of `()` around the `|`.